# Online Python bot that uses cmd and files

Tags: python, cmd, cloud, instagram, replit

I'm trying to program a bot running 24/7 that checks new posts of some accounts on Instagram. I found out the best scraper for me is `instagram-scraper`, but it only runs in cmd and downloads images in a file on my computer. So I need an online server that can run cmd commands, create and use the file to store images.

I found the website *replit.com* which provides setting bots in the cloud.

I don't know where to start even searching how to use cmd, files, and all stuff on *replit.com*. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

To use a bot that has folder access on services like replit or pythonanywhere, you might want to start with the path of your workspace. `__ROOTFOLDER__ = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` will give you your current working directory, and you can feed or use data from the workspace.

For the CMD part, you can call the command line via the `os` library. Keep in mind that CMD has a character limitation.

```py
os.system('YOUR LINE HERE')
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to download files in the project without accessing my device at no level.
Also in how does cmd work with replit.com does it create like a virtual command, I am asking because I need to install instagram-scraper via pip and I don't know if it will work with cloud hosting